# Static variable order

Tags: c#, .net, static-variables

I have aproblem with the order of static variable declaration in C#

When i run this code:

```
static class Program {
  private static int v1 = 15;
  private static int v2 = v1;

  static void Main(string[] args) {
   Console.WriteLine("v2 = "+v2);
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
v2=15
```

But when i change the static variable declaration order like this:

```
 static class Program {
      private static int v2 = v1;
      private static int v1 = 15;


      static void Main(string[] args) {
       Console.WriteLine("v2 = "+v2);
      }
    }
```

The Output is:

```
v2 = 0
```

Why this happend?

Comment: This is not declarative programming, like in Prolog. In C# Commands have an order they are run. In this case, it is straightforward...

Comment: Did you know that if you define v1 like: 'private const int v1 = 15;' you get 15 instead of 0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The static fields are initialized in the same order as the declarations. When you initialize `v2` with the value of `v1`, `v1` is not initialized yet, so its value is 0.

Answer (score 4):

Static variables are initialized in their order of declaration, so when you are assigning `v2` in your second example, `v1` still has its default value `0`.

I hope you know that doing things like this is a bad idea though.

Answer (score 2):

The way static variables get there value means that in the second example, `v1` is not initialized and so takes on the default value of 0 when it is assigned to `v2`.

Answer (score 2):

The `static` fields initialized  same order as follows their declarations.

In your second code, `v1` isn't initialized. Since `v1` is `Int32`, so it is a *value type*, and all value types default value is `0`.

> From  C#4.0 in a Nutshell on page 74.
>
> Static field initializers run in the order in which the fields are
>   declared.

In your case;

```
private static int v2 = v1;
// v2 initialized 0 because of the default value of value types.
private static int v1 = 15;
// v1 initialized 15
```